# In SPSS Python essentials, can I get the value of an SPSS variable returned to Python for further use?

Tags: python, variables, namespaces, spss

I have a database where each case holds info about handwritten digits, eg:

Digit1Seq : when in the sequence of 12 digits the "1" was drawn

Digit1Ht:   the height of the digit "1"

Digit1Width: its width

Digit2Seq: same info for digit "2"

on up to digit "12"

I find I now need the information organized a little differently as well. In particular I want a new variables with the height and width of the *first* digit written, then the height and width of the *second*, etc., as SPSS vars

FirstDigitHt

FirstDigitWidth ...

TwelvthDigitWidth

Here's a Python program I wrote to do within SPSS what ought to be a very simple computation, but it runs into a sort of namespace problem:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.

import spss
indices = ["1", "2", "3","4","5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]
seq=0
for i in indices:
  spss.Submit("COMPUTE seq = COMDigit" + i + "Seq.")
  spss.Submit("EXECUTE.")
  spss.Submit("COMPUTE COM" + indices[seq] + "thWidth =  COMDigit" + i + "Width.")
  spss.Submit("COMPUTE COM" + indices[seq] + "thHgt =  COMDigit" + i + "Hgt.")
  spss.Submit("EXECUTE.")

END PROGRAM.
```

It's clear what's wrong here: the value of `seq` in the first `COMPUTE` command doesn't get back to Python, so that the right thing can happen in the next two `COMPUTE`commands. Python's value of `seq` doesn't change, so I end up with SPSS code that gives me only two variables (`COM1thWidth` and `COM1Hgt`), into which `COMDigit1Width`, `COMDigit2Width`, etc. get written.

Is there any way to get Python to access SPSS's value of `seq` each time so that the string concatenation will create the correct `COMPUTE`? Or am I just thinking about this incorrectly?

Have googled extensively, but find no way to do this.

As I'm new to using Python in SPSS (and not all that much of wiz with SPSS) there may well be a far easier way to do this.

All suggestions most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to get your SPSS variable data into Python variables for manipulation is with the spss.Dataset class.

To do this, You will need: 
1.) the dataset name of your SPSS Dataset
2.) either the name of the variable you want to pull data from or its index in your dataset.

If the name of the variable you want to extract data from is named 'seq' (as I believe it was in your question), then you can use something like:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.
from __future__ import with_statement
import spss
with spss.DataStep()
    #the lines below create references to your dataset,
    #to its variable list, and to its case data
    lv_dataset = spss.Dataset(name = <name of your SPSS dataset>)
    lv_caseData = lv_dataset.cases
    lv_variables = lv_dataset.varlist

    #the line below extracts all the data from the SPSS variable named 'seq' in the dataset referenced above into a list
    #to make use of an SPSS cases object, you specify in square brackets which rows and which variables to extract from, such as:
    #Each row you request to be extracted will be returned as a list of values, one value for each variable you request data for
    #lv_theData = lv_caseData[rowStartIndex:rowEndIndex, columnStartIndex:columnEndIndex]

    #This means that if you want to get data for one variable across many rows of data, you will get a list for each row of data, but each row's list will have only one value in it, hence in the code below, we grab the first element of each list returned
    lv_variableData = [itm[0] for itm in lv_caseData[0:len(lv_caseData), lv_variables['seq'].index]]

END PROGRAM.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to process the case data held by Statistics via Python, but the case data has to be read explicitly using the spss.Cursor, spssdata.Spssdata, or spss.Dataset class.  It does not live in the Python namespace.

In this case the simplest thing to do would be to just substitute the formula for seq into the later references. There are many other ways to tackle this.

Also, get rid of those EXECUTE calls.  They just force unnecessary data passes.  Statistics will automatically pass the data when it needs to based on the command stream.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't quite follow; by "substitute the formula", do you mean spss.Submit("COMPUTE COM" + indices["COMDigit" + i + "Seq"] + "thWidth =  COMDigit" + i + "Width.") ?? This looks like it has the same namespace issue. Or am I missing what you're suggesting? Thanks!

Comment: Apparently there will be no further explanation from JKP. Should he/she every come back here, may I point out how annoyingly useless a reply is that says "there are lots of ways" and "there are many other ways to tackle this" if you don't actually ever explain any of them. Really quite useless.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just stumbled across this, and you've probably moved on, but it might help other folks.  I don't thing you actually need to access have Python access the SPSS values.  I think something like this might work:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.

import spss

for i in range(1,13):
  k = "COMPUTE seq = COMDigit" + str(i) + "Seq."
  l = "Do if seq = " + str(i)+ "."
  m = "COMPUTE COM" + str(i) + "thWidth =  COMDigit" + str(i) + "Width."
  n = "COMPUTE COM" + str(i) + "thHgt =  COMDigit" + str(i) + "Hgt."
  o = "End if."
  print k
  print l
  print m
  print n
  print o
  spss.Submit(k)
  spss.Submit(l)
  spss.Submit(m)
  spss.Submit(n)
  spss.Submit(o)

spss.Submit("EXECUTE.")
END PROGRAM.
```

But I'd have to see the data to make sure I'm understanding your problem correctly. Also, the print stuff makes the code look ugly, but its the only way I can keep a handle on whats going on under the hood.  Cheerio!